# How to join two T-SQL statements

Tags: sql-server

I have problem regarding sql, I want to join two sql statements.

1st one

```
"Select * from [PhotoStatusProfile] WHERE Email IN (Select Friend1 from [Friendship] WHERE Friend2 = '" + Session["Email"].ToString() + "' AND Friend_Status =1 UNION Select Friend2 from [Friendship] WHERE Friend1 = '" + Session["Email"].ToString() + "' AND Friend_Status =1 ) UNION Select * From PhotoStatusProfile WHERE Email='" + Session["Email"] + "' order by Date desc", con);
```

2nd one

```
Select * from UserData WHERE Email='"+Session["Email"]+"'
```

This is I tried code, but it gives me errors

```
"Select * from [PhotoStatusProfile] WHERE Email IN (Select Friend1 from [Friendship] WHERE Friend2 = '" + Session["Email"].ToString() + "' AND Friend_Status =1 UNION Select Friend2 from [Friendship] WHERE Friend1 = '" + Session["Email"].ToString() + "' AND Friend_Status =1 ) UNION Select * From PhotoStatusProfile WHERE Email='" + Session["Email"] + "' order by Date desc UNION Select * from UserData WHERE Email='"+Session["Email"]+"'
```

`UserData` table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserData] 
(
    [YourName]       VARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [Email]          VARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [Password]       VARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [Gender]         VARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [Birthday]       VARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [AboutMe]        VARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [Country]        VARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [ID]             NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [ProfilePic]     NVARCHAR (500) NULL,
    [ProfilePicPath] NVARCHAR (500) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_UserData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Email] ASC)
);
```

`PhotoStatusProfile` table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PhotoStatusProfile] 
(
    [Name]       VARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [Status]     VARCHAR (5000) NULL,
    [Photo]      NVARCHAR (500) NULL,
    [Email]      VARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [Date]       DATETIME       NULL,
    [ID]         NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [ProfilePic] NVARCHAR (500) NULL,
    [PosterID]   VARCHAR (50)   NULL
);
```

Comment: Are the columns of these tables same?

Comment: I think Jayvee has a point, which makes me ask: have you copy/pasted your code form an ASP.NET page to a SQL server? If that's the case you need to change some values to make the SQL work.

Answer (score 0):

Always Check State Variables for null like `Sessions,ViewStates`

```
SqlParameter para=new SqlParameter("@Email",SQLDb.Varchar,50);
if(Session["Email"]!=null)
{
para.Value=Session["Email"].ToString();
}
else
{
para.Value="";
}
```

Then Try this

```
"Select * from [PhotoStatusProfile] WHERE Email 
IN (Select Friend1 from [Friendship] 
WHERE Friend2 = @Email
AND Friend_Status =1 UNION Select Friend2 from 
[Friendship] WHERE Friend1 = @Email
AND Friend_Status =1 ) UNION Select ColumnName From PhotoStatusProfile
WHERE Email=@Email order by Date desc", con);
```

Column Names should be Equal when using `UNION` You are using `*` in Your Last `Union`

**Always use `SqlParameters` Beware of SQL Injection**

Comment: How to connect Select * from UserData WHERE Email='"+Session["Email"]+"' code to your sql code?

Answer (score 0):

The UNION operation have some constraints. Look at following constraints from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp):

> Notice that each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types. Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order.

Comment: ah, okay, then tell me how to join two table queries? what is the proper query for that?

Comment: @Prabath: Use W3schools to learn about it. In your case select the columns with same type in same order like I said. I don't know your tables' columns.

Comment: @Prabath: What do you want to do? What do you want to have?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you want to JOIN based on email and creating the sql strings in a .NET program. If my assumptions are correct then it should be something like this:

```
"Select * from 
(Select * from [PhotoStatusProfile] WHERE Email 
IN 
(Select Friend1 from [Friendship] WHERE Friend2 = '" + Session["Email"].ToString() + "' AND Friend_Status =1 
UNION 
Select Friend2 from [Friendship] WHERE Friend1 = '" + Session["Email"].ToString() + "' AND Friend_Status =1 ) 
UNION Select * From PhotoStatusProfile WHERE Email='" + Session["Email"] + "' ) a 
JOIN UserData b on a.Email=b.Email order by Date desc", con)
```